# DirectLineJS isn't working in FireFox, works in Edge and Chrome

Tags: javascript, rxjs, direct-line-botframework

In the chat UI that I made, I connect with directline as indicated in the docs (var directLine = new DirectLine.DirectLine({secret: directLineSecret});) it works perfectly with Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but with firefox it just doesn't connect. When typing in the console the command, it creates a directLine object without a conversation id; therefore, everything that I type doesn't get a response.

[Here's is how I create the DirectLine object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxnN8.jpg)

Also my listener when posting activities to directLine prints in console a message with the id on success, and the error otherwise, but none of the listeners is executing.

```
var dlobj = new DirectLine.DirectLine({secret: "myDirectLineSecret"});
var activity = { 
        from:{
            id:"User", 
            name: "User"
        }, 
        type: "message", 
        text: "I'm here"
};
dlobj.postActivity(activity)
    .subscribe(
        id => console.log("Success: ",id), 
        error => console.log("Error: ", error)
    );
```

Output in Chrome:

"Success:  A2CflFKTt5j11hPQcDtte|0000001"

In firefox no message is printed, nor error nor success.

Anybody has any idea of the reason this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible cause was, in effect, a difference in permissions of firefox and Chrome.